# react-switch-button can NOT updated by setState

Tags: reactjs

i am newbie in React and recently kick start learning and playing around some third-party components. One trying is (http://gfazioli.github.io/react-switch-button/#demo)

Thus, very soon encounter a silly problem (may be just i can't figure it out how). On below sample, i just can't update the SwitchButton to false state to true. Suppose i try using the button click to trigger the update on SwitchButton but i can't just make it work.

The 'checked' property is String type, tried ('true'|'false'|'checked'|'') or even getting bk to use Boolean but still NO luck, also can NOT see any other property that it could trigger an update on SwitchButton

Grateful if anyone could help a newbie. Many Thanks

```
import React from 'react'
import SwitchButton from 'react-switch-button'
import 'react-switch-button/dist/react-switch-button.css'

export default class Demo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      testChecked: 'false'
    };

    this.onButtonClick = this.onButtonClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.state.testChecked)
  }

  onButtonClick(){
    this.setState({
      testChecked: 'true'
    });
    console.log(this.state.testChecked);
  }

  render() {
    return(
        <div>
          react-switch-button
          <br/><br/>
          <input type='button' value='click' onClick={this.onButtonClick} />
          <br/>
          {this.state.testChecked}:
          <SwitchButton name='switch-1' defaultChecked={false} checked={this.state.testChecked} />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the property `checked` is not being used as far as I can see it in the source here https://github.com/gfazioli/react-switch-button/blob/master/src/react-switch-button.js

With that in mind you want to use the `defaultChecked` props for switching the state e.g.

```
<SwitchButton name='switch-1' defaultChecked={this.state.testChecked} />
```

It's from type `React.PropTypes.bool` and not `React.PropTypes.string` you have change your state `testChecked` to that.

Comment: Many Thanks Murat
Tried using defaultChecked with boolean property, it doesn't work too
Anyway, thanks for ur answer, i have change using another component instead (this one work - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toggle-switch)